# Define a rule to determine if a list contains a given member

Tags: list, prolog

I have recently started learning prolog, and facing a problem with this question:

> Define a rule to determine if a list contains a given member.

I searched all over stack overflow to get some links to understand this problem better and write solutions for it but couldn't find anything. Could anyone of you advice to solve this particular problem?

My Approach:

```
Iterative over the list and see if your member matches with head:

on(Item,[Item|Rest]).  /* is my target item on the list */

on(Item,[DisregardHead|Tail]):-


          on(Item,Tail).
```

Do you think my approach is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct and works in all directions. Nice!

Notes:

1. Your solution is in fact more general than what the task asks for. This is a good thing! The task, in my view, is badly worded. First of all, the first clause is not a *rule*, but a *fact*. It would have been better to formulate the task like: "Write a Prolog program that is true **if** a term occurs in a list." This leaves open other use cases that a good solution will *also* automatically solve, such as *generating* solutions.
2. This common predicate is widely known as `member/2`. Just like your solution, it also works in all directions. Try for example `?- member(E, Ls).`
3. The name for the predicate could be better. A good naming convention for Prolog makes clear what each argument means. Consider for example: `element_list/2`, and start from there.

Comment: Thanks :) your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

What you have is indeed a "correct" implementation. The standard name for a predicate that does that is `member/2`, and is available (under that name) in any Prolog, and should be quite easy to find once you know its name.

Some things to note however. First, with the classical definition (this is exactly as in "The Art of Prolog" by Sterling and Shapiro, p. 58, and identical to yours):

```
member_classic(X, [X|Xs]).
member_classic(X, [Y|Ys]) :-
    member_classic(X, Ys).
```

If you try to compile this, you will get singleton errors. This is because you have named variables that appear only once in their scope: the `Xs` in the first clause and the `Y` in the second. This aside, here is what the program does:

```
?- member_classic(c, [a,b,c,x]).
true ;
false.

?- member_classic(c, [c]).
true ;
false.

?- member_classic(X, [a,b,c]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
false.
```

In other words, with this definition, Prolog will leave behind a choice point even when it is quite obvious that there could not be further solutions (because it is at the end of the list). One way to avoid this is to use a technique called "lagging", as demonstrated by the [SWI-Prolog library implementation of `member/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/lists.pl?show=src#member/2).

And another thing: with your current problem statement, it might be that this is considered undesirable behaviour:

```
?- member_classic(a, [a,a,a]).
true ;
true ;
true ;
false.
```

There is another predicate usually called `member_check/2` or `memberchk/2` which does **exactly** what you have written, namely, succeeds or fails exactly once:

```
?- memberchk(a, [a,a,a]).
true.

?- memberchk(a, [x,y,z]).
false.
```

It has, however, the following behaviour when the first argument is a variable that might be undesirable:

```
?- memberchk(X, [a,b,c]).
X = a. % no more solutions!
```

There are valid uses for both `member/2` and `memberchk/2` IMHO (but interestingly enough, some people might argue otherwise).